# many classes inside a class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

The language I use is C#.

I have a problem of architectural nature. Let Class A has the following form:

```
Class A
{
    Class B
    {
        // properties goes here.
    }

    Class C
    {
       // properties goes here.
    }

    Class D
    {
        // properties goes here.
    }

   ....

   private ClassA methodX
   {
       // code goes here
   }  

   private ClassB methodY
   {
       // code goes here
   }

   private ClassC methodZ
   {
       // code goes here
   }

   ....
}
```

The classes B, C and D are classes that hold only properties. They don't express any behaviour through a public method. My problem about this approach is that the code of class A is too huge. So the future maintainance of class A will be difficult.

My question is should I remove the classes B, C and D to seperate files or should I leave them there as they are in class A?

Is there a better approach to handle the above problem?

One of my concerns, if I should put this code to separate files, is that I have also other classes like `class A`. So, there would be a significant increase in the number of files that my application has.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I recommand you, one file for one class. As you said, maintenance become difficult when each class grown, so, imagine how it will be with 4 class inside a file.

Comment: It's not like you have to change all of your classes just because Class A happened to become too big for comfort. Split class A up and keep the rest like they are. However, I wouldn't worry so much about amount of files... just use folders to keep them organized and it shouldn't be problematic for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move them out of class A, into their own files and make them internal classes, this will achieve both keeping them private (with respect to other assemblies) and keep your classes at a more manageable size.

From experience, large numbers of files are not a problem as long as your classes are well named and the files are organised into sub-folders, with matching namespaces.